# Error parsing XML using DOM in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, dom

I have an XML file from a web service. I'm trying to parse it using Microsoft XML v6 objects in VBA. My code is:

```
Public Sub LoadDocument()
Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
resp = xDoc.Load("c:\xmlsoccer - scot prem.txt")
Debug.Print xDoc.parseError.errorCode
Debug.Print xDoc.parseError.reason
Debug.Print xDoc.parseError.Line
End Sub
```

resp returns false and the error reason is "Invalid at the top level of the document."

The XML string starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLSOCCER.COM>
    <Match>
        <Id>70146</Id>
        <FixtureMatch_Id>332875</FixtureMatch_Id>
        <Date>2014-05-11T11:15:00+00:00</Date>
        <Round>38</Round>
        <Spectators>17011</Spectators>
        <League>Scottish Premier League</League>
        <HomeTeam>Aberdeen</HomeTeam>
        <HomeTeam_Id>45</HomeTeam_Id>
    ....
```

I tried deleting the first line but get the same error. Is the text in the right format? Don't know much about XML so not even sure I can load this into the DOM objects.

Comment: Check whether the xml whether it is valid or not ?

Comment: What's with the dashes? Paste your XML [here](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the link.Seems that it's not formatted correctly. Error is "content not allowed in Prolog" for the first line.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you add reference to Microsoft XML, V6.0 to VBA module.  I used the following XML without issues with your code :

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLSOCCER.COM>
  <Match>
    <Id>70146</Id>
    <FixtureMatch_Id>332875</FixtureMatch_Id>
    <Date>2014-05-11T11:15:00+00:00</Date>
    <Round>38</Round>
    <Spectators>17011</Spectators>
    <League>Scottish Premier League</League>
    <HomeTeam>Aberdeen</HomeTeam>
    <HomeTeam_Id>45</HomeTeam_Id>
  </Match>
</XMLSOCCER.COM>​
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the dashes that were causing the problem. Thanks Bond. Also some special characters caused it to fail. Once I removed the dashes and replaced the special characters it worked fine.